# Even TestNG is installed in Eclipse, TestNG is not showing in eclipse run configurations

Tags: testng-eclipse

I have installed Testng in eclispe via eclipse install software option, but it not showing in the run configuration. I am not able to run my testng program as TestNg test

Ubuntu version: **22.04.2**,
Java Jdk : **11.0.19**,
Eclipse : **2022-12 (4.26.0)**,
TestNG Plugin: **7.8.0**,
TestNG: **7.8.0**

this is a maven project :

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class FirstProject {

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    System.out.println("haii");
}
```

}

[TestNG installation details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWQI8.png)
[Run Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM3ft.png)

Please help me to resolve this issue. I have uninstalled and reinstalled  testng plugin a lot of time. But still it is not working.